# What is it called to attack a person then say something uplifting?

Tags: social-psychology, terminology, behavior

Say a manager emailing the people under her in a way that to them feels degrading, and putting down. But at the end of the email its encouraging/uplifting type saying I know you are intelligent and capable people.

So is there a name of this type of behavior to attack/degrade then at the end say something nice?

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help. Gave me quite a bit to lookup. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like a variant on the [**sandwich technique**](https://www.findlay.edu/blog/feedback-sandwich-approach), which is advocated by some as the preferred way to deliver critical feedback to a person, like a student or employee. The sandwich technique can be defined as:

> ...offer[ing] a piece of negative feedback “sandwiched" between two positive
>   ones, thus easing the blow of the critique.

Note that this technique is criticized, because people might not remember the crucial middle critical part of the message, because of the **[recency effect](https://psychology.iresearchnet.com/social-psychology/decision-making/recency-effect/)**: our brains are hardwired to remember the first and last bits of a conversation whilst glossing over the middle part (source: [WeQ](https://www.weq.io/post/why-the-sandwich-feedback-doesnt-work-and-what-to-do-instead)).

Answer (score 2):

The closest thing I can think of to what you are talking about is loosely referred to as 'Push-Pull'. It happens in a lot of unhealthy relationships and is a favorite tactic of so-called pickup artists. Used appropriately it can be healthy, but it is typically a manipulation tactic. https://outofthefog.website/top-100-trait-blog/2015/11/4/push-pull

Comment: This reminds me of the cycle of abuse

Answer (score 1):

**Sugarcoat** also fits. If this is intentional in order to have them under control, this can be said as a form of **manipulation**.

A reverse effect that the actor may not be aware of that the recipient chose to remember the good information only. This can be described as **cherrypick**.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure it has an established name, (perhaps "lead with the negative",  "bad news first", or “get the bad news out of the way”) but [research](https://doi.org/10.1177%2F0146167213509113) suggests that people prefer to hear the bad news before the good ones... even though that might lower their chances of changing behavior in reaction to the bad news. (For a free but longer summary of the study see [this PT page](https://www.psychologytoday.com/ca/blog/ulterior-motives/201406/why-hearing-good-news-or-bad-news-first-really-matters)).

The body of research in this area is fairly thin though, so I wouldn't put too much stock in it.